# Printing row cell values in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I would like to print the values in an Excel Row. I can get to the row and select it, but how do i loop through the cells? Or is there a row object that i can read?

```
Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

        r = Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Select

        For Each cell In r.Cells
            Debug.Print cell.Value
        Next cell

    Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that doing `Do Until`IsEmpty(ActiveCell)` isn't a good idea:
you could have some empty cells followed by non-empty cells.

How does this code work for you?

```
Sub print_some_values()

    Dim c As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim max_col As Long

    r = ActiveCell.Row
    max_col = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For c = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
       Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c).Value
    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but this code prints the current row until an empty cell is found

```
Sub a()

Dim r As Range
Dim c As Range

    Set r = Rows(ActiveCell.Row)
    For Each c In r.Cells
        If (IsEmpty(c)) Then Exit For
        Debug.Print c.Value
    Next c
```

**Edit**

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Sub a()

Dim TheArray As Variant

TheArray = Range("A4:E4").Value
Debug.Print TheArray(1, 4)

End Sub
```

Comment: Just to clarify my use case i want to go through all rows, reading values and sending them to SQL Server. Is there a better way to do this? I was expecting to treat a row as a recordset row, funny Excel doesn't have anything better to read values in rows.

Comment: Is this seriously the only MS reference for Excel? 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272268%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Comment: @L. De Leo Sorry, really don't know. I usually browse the web when in need. MS doc organization makes me cry.

Comment: Your first approach inspired my solution, together with some hints from Adam. Thanks both

Answer (score 0):

I used a mixed approach, the ">" tells me if the row is dirty (has been edited)

```
Dim r As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim max_col As Long

max_col = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Debug.Print ActiveCell.Value

    If ActiveCell.Value = ">" Then
        Set r = Rows(ActiveCell.Row)

        For Each c In r.Cells
            'print the value of each cell in the row
            If c.Column = 1 Then
                'skip
            ElseIf c.Column <= max_col Then
                Debug.Print c.Value
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
    End If

    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop
```